# Is there an analog of ArcGIS Desktop's “Results” tab in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, results-window

I want to rerun previously started QGIS tools without manually specifying inputs again. ArcGIS "Results" tab save all input parameters so I can double click on it and start tool again without retyping all inputs.

**How can I do the same using QGIS?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a "History" which allows you to run the last operation you did but without the possibility to change any values. However, if you change the geometry of the input values the results will reflect that change. (e.x. change/add a point to a shapefile and the count will be updated)

you can find it under Processing -> History. Just double-click on an entry and you will run the algorithm

[image: history and an algorithem]

Comment: The inability to change parameters is frustrating.

Comment: @Mr.Che True, a workaround could be to use a batch process to get different results. Then again you will get a lots of data which you wont need

Comment: @Mr.Che you could also use a relational database and save your SQL queries/processes as files and use those instead of the dialogue boxes. Just because something 'exists' in ArcGIS doesn't mean it should exist in QGIS, or if its even a best practice when working with spatial data.